# In the C++ standard, where does it indicate the spacing protocol for the replacement of category descriptives by the source code it represents?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

At the risk of asking a question deemed too nit-picky, I have spent a long time trying to justify (as a single example of something that occurs throughout the standard in different contexts) the following definition of an `integer literal` in §2.14.2 of the C++11 standard, specifically in regards to one detail, the presence of whitespace in the syntax notation itself.

(Note that this example - the definition of an integer literal - is not the point of my question.  The point of my question is to ask about the syntax description notation used by the C++ standard *itself*, specifically in regards to whitespace between grammatical category names.  The example I give here - the definition of an integer literal - is specifically chosen *only* because it acts as an example that is simple and clear-cut.)

(Abbreviated for concision, from §2.14.2):

```
integer-literal:
    decimal-literal integer-suffix_opt

decimal-literal:
    nonzero-digit
    decimal-literal digit
```

(with `nonzero-digit` and `digit` as expected, [0] 1 ... 9).  (Note: The above text is all in italics in the standard.)

This all makes sense to me, assuming that the SPACE between the syntax category descriptives *`decimal-literal`* and *`digit`* is understood to NOT be present in the actual source code, but is only present in the syntax description itself as it appears here in section §2.14.2.

This convention - placing a space between category descriptives within the notation, where it is understood that the space is not to be present in the source code - is used in other places in the specification.  The example here is just a clear-cut case where the space is clearly not supposed to be present in the source code.  (See addendum to this question for counterexamples from the standard where whitespace or other separator/s *must* be present, or is optional, between category descriptives when those category descriptives are replaced by actual tokens in the source code.)

Again, at the risk of being nit-picky, I cannot find anywhere in the standard a statement of convention that spaces are NOT to be present in the source code when interpreting notation such as in this example.

The standard does discuss notational convention in §1.6.1 (and thereafter).  The only relevant text that I can find regarding this is:

> In the syntax notation used in this International Standard, syntactic
>   categories are indicated by italic type, and literal words and
>   characters in constant width type. Alternatives are listed on separate
>   lines except in a few cases where a long set of alternatives is marked
>   by the phrase “one of.”

I would not be so nit-picky; however, I find the notation used within the standard to be somewhat tricky, so I would like to be clear on all of the details.  I appreciate anyone willing to take the time to fill me in on this.

**ADDENDUM**  In response to comments in which a claim is made similar to "*it's obvious that whitespace should not be included in the final source code, so there's no need for the standard to explicitly state this*": I have chosen a trivial example in this question, where it *is* obvious.  There are many cases in the standard where it *isn't* obvious without a. priori knowledge of the language (in my opinion), such as §8.0.4 discussing "const" and "volatile":

```
cv-qualifier-seq:
    cv-qualifier cv-qualifier-seq_opt
```

... Note the *opposite* assumption here (whitespace, or another separator or separators, is *required* in the final source code), but that's not possible to deduce from the syntax notation itself.

There are also cases where a space is *optional*, such as:

```
noptr-abstract-declarator:
    noptr-abstract-declarator_opt parameters-and-qualifiers
```

(In this example, to make a point, I won't give the section number or paraphrase what is being discussed; I'll just ask if it's obvious from the grammar notation itself that, in *this* context, whitespace in the final source code is optional between the tokens.)

I suspect that the comments along these lines - "it's obvious, so that's what it must be" - are the result of the fact that the example I've chosen is so obvious.  That's exactly why I chose the example.

Comment: Those are English names for tokens, written in the English language. You're reading English. Words are separated by spaces. The spec doesn't need to redefine how the English language works.

Comment: I'm sure that if a space were to be required it would have to be explicitly stated `decimal-literal SPACE digit` - that's why you can assume if it isn't explicitly stated it isn't there. Unless you have found an exception? - (btw I liked your last 2 questions)

Comment: @meager That has nothing to do with my question.  My question is in regard to replacing the tokens with what they represent in source code.

Comment: @Caribou Can you find that in the specification?  I can't.  Elsewhere in the specification, any characters outside of the italicized text must be present in the source code itself - such as curly braces.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Not directly, but §2.6 defines alternative tokens (including ones for '{' and '}' indicating that braces (2 groups of 1 literal) are tokens in the same way as decimal-literal (group of literals). spaces are used as a separator for the grammar in the standard and in an intuitive(? natural at least) way. I believe it is safe to assume whitespace is merely separating tokens in the standard Unless *explicitly* stated : E.G. `As described in Clause 16, in certain circumstances ..., white space (or the absence thereof) serves as more than preprocessing token separation.`

Comment: Question addended to supply not-so-obvious counterexamples.

Comment: Did everyone miss the quote: `This summary of C++ syntax is intended to be an aid to comprehension. It is not an exact statement
of the language`? The spaces are insignificant and are there for legibility, that is all.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for highlighting that.  I wonder where the exact statement of the language is to be found?  I guess the case of spaces is just considered to be *obvious* so it isn't specified.  I don't see any other ambiguities anywhere in the definitions (besides spaces).  So if spaces are the only issue and it's always obvious how to handle them, it's really no big deal, as GManNickG says in a comment below.  I guess that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the standard says:

> literal words and characters in constant width type

So, if a literal space were to be included in a rule, it would have to be rendered in a constant width type. Close examination of the standard will reveal that the space in the production you refer to is narrower than the constant width type. (Also your attempt to quote the standard is a misrepresentation because it renders in constant-width type that which should be rendered in italics, with a consequent semantic change.)

---

Ok, that was the "aspiring language lawyer" answer; furthermore, it doesn't really work because it fails on all the productions which are of the form:

```
One of:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I think, in reality, the answer is that whitespace is not part of the formal grammar, because it serves only to separate tokens; furthermore, that statement is mostly true of the grammar itself, whose tokens are separated by whitespace without that whitespace being a token, except that indentation in the grammar matters, unlike indentation in a program.

---

**Addendum to answer the addendum**

It's not actually true that `const` and `volatile` need to be separated by whitespace. They simply need to be separate tokens. Example:

```
#define A(x)x
A(const)A(volatile)A(int)A(x)A(;)
```

Again, more seriously, Chapter 2 (with particular reference to 2.2 and 2.5, but you have to read the entire text) describe how the program text is processed in order to produce a stream of tokens. All of the rules in which you claim whitespace must be ignored are in this part of the grammar, and all of the rules in which you claim whitespace might be required are not.

These are really two separate grammars, but the lexical grammar is necessarily incomplete because you need to consider the operation of the preprocessor in order to apply it.

I believe that everything I said can be gleaned from the standard. Here are some excerpts:

> 2.2(3) The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens (2.5) and sequences of white-space characters (including comments)… The process of dividing a source file’s characters into preprocessing tokens is context-dependent.
>
> …
>
> 2.2(7) White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. (2.7). The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

I think that all this makes it clear that there are two grammars, one lexical -- that is, it produces a lexeme (token) from a sequence of graphemes (characters) -- and the other syntactic -- that is, it produces an abstract syntax tree from a sequence of lexemes (tokens). In neither case (with a small exception, which I'll get to in a minute) is whitespace considered anything other than something which stops two lexemes from running into each other if the lexical grammar would otherwise allow that. (See the algorithm in 2.5(3).)

`C++` is not syntactically pretty, so there are almost always exceptions. One of these, inherited from `C`, is the difference between:

```
#define A(X)(X)
```

and

```
#define A (X)(X)
```

Preprocessing directives have their own parsing rules, and this one is typified by the definition:

> *lparen*:
>   a `(` character not immediately preceded by white-space

This, I would say, is the exception that proves the rule [Note 1]. The fact that it is necessary to say that this `(` is not preceded by white-space shows that the normal use of the token `(` in a syntactic rule does not say anything about its blancospatial context.

So, to paraphrase Ray Cummings (not Albert Einstein, as is sometimes claimed), "time and white-space are all that separate one token from another." [Note 2]

---

[Note 1] I use the phrase here in its original legal sense, as per[Cicero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule).

[Note 2]:

> "Time," said George, "why I can give you a definition of time. It's what keeps everything from happening at once."
>
> A ripple of laughter went about the little group of men.
>
> "Quite so," agreed the Chemist. "And, gentlemen, that's not so funny as it sounds. As a matter of fact, it is really not a bad scientific definition. Time and space are all that separate one event from another…

-- From *The man who mastered time*, by Ray Cummings, 1929, Ace Books. See [first page, in Google books](http://books.google.com.pe/books?id=Imx5-W7OAbwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: I've given some counterexamples to "*tokens are separated by whitespace without that whitespace being a token*" (in an addendum to the question).

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: I provided an addendum to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I've read all of §2.2 through $2.5 carefully, and I don't think they apply in any way to the syntax used in the syntax description notation itself.  I think they apply only to the character sequence in the source code file (starting at the point before any preprocessing, so the rules for preprocessing are also included in §2).  I'm aware that hunting through the standard is a hassle and I appreciate your comments and answer.

Comment: I've updated the addendum in my answer to clarify that it is *whitespace, or another separator or separators* that must be present in the source code - whitespace is not the only possible separator, but a separator or separators is required.

Comment: I love the quote.  I think that "*white-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant*" refers to *after* tokenization - but the presence of whitespace in the original source code is critical to make the separation points between tokens clear, just as you say: "*in neither case is whitespace considered anything other than something which stops two lexemes from running into each other*".  The integer literal example is trivial, but I'm just mentioning that clearly there can be no whitespace present, or else tokenization will fail, and you can't tell that from the specification.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, you can tell that from the spec. 2.5(2) "White space can appear within a preprocessing token only as part of a header name or between the quotation characters in a character literal or string literal." And 2.5(3), "Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a
preprocessing token..." Between the two of those, it's easy to prove that there cannot be whitespace between digits in a single number, and there must be whitespace (or something) between two consecutive keywords.

Comment: You nailed it on the money. Thanks. The logic is the following: §2.2.3 "*the source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters*". §2.5 defines one of the preproc tokens as "*pp-number*" which therefore can have no space.  §2.10.1 states that pp-number tokens "*lexically include all integral literal tokens*". Then, §2.2.7: "*each preprocessing token is converted into a token*" (and §2.5.1 confirms this). The literal therefore cannot have spaces. In the case of `const`, `volatile`, etc, in order to parse as distinct tokens, they *must* have separation.

Answer (score 8):

§2.7.1

> There are five kinds of tokens: identifiers, keywords, literals,
>   operators, and other separators. Blanks, horizontal and vertical tabs,
>   newlines, formfeeds, and comments (collectively, “white space”), as
>   described below, are ignored **except as they serve to separate tokens**.

So, if a literal is a token, and whitespace serves to seperate tokens, space in between the digits of a literal would be interpreted as two separate tokens, and therefore cannot be part of the same literal.

Comment: The question is about the wording in the grammar specification, not about tokens in the language itself.

Comment: @Xeo This wording defines how the language handles whitespace *so the grammar spec syntax doesn't have to*. +1

Comment: See the specification of translation phases. Tokenization happens before processing the grammar.

Comment: This quote from the standard is in regards to whitespace within the source code itself - not to white space within the standard's syntax notation.  My question is in regards to the whitespace that appears in the standard's syntax notation - literally the text itself that appears in §2.14.2.  In that text there is a blank space between the two italicized categorical identifiers *`decimal-literal`* and *`digit`*. Were this same space to appear in the actual source code when these categorical identifiers were replaced with actual digits, it would not form a correct integer literal.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: See Barmar's comment.  The whitespace is eliminated by tokenization, so by the time the compiler gets to the point where it is analyzing syntax, the whitespace is gone.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's my understanding that continguous whitespace is replaced by a single whitespace character.  I am not talking about the tokenization phase.  I am talking about the actual text of the syntax notation in the standard document itself - literally the text *`decimal-literal digit`* - not text in the source code.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Okay, now I understand. I don't think you'll find such a mention in the standard.  The way I see it, there are two ways for the implementer to interpret it: Either don't interpret spaces in the grammar as literal space, or require numbers to be written like this: `1 2 3 4 5 . 6 7 8 9`, and identifiers to be written like this: `M y C l a s s`, among other absurdities. The latter is ridiculous, so having to explain that it is the former should not be necessary.  When writing a specification, you have to draw the line somewhere in your assumptions, and I think this is a safe one.

Comment: This is exactly why I chose this particular example - of many where it is not so obvious: Precisely because it's obvious in this case.  In other cases, it's not clear to me if the space should be present in the final source code (without a priori knowledge of the language), such as §8.0.4 *`cv-qualifier-seq:
cv-qualifier cv-qualifier-seqopt`* (with "cv-qualifier" being "const" or "volatile").  This grammar syntax is identical to that in my "clear-cut" example (a space between the category identifiers), but it is clear (from my knowledge of C++) that a space *must* be present.

Comment: I have addended my question to make it clear that I've deliberatly chosen an obvious example for the sake of my question, and I've given two counterexamples.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: contiguous whitespace is _not_ replaced by a single space.  After tokenization, _there are no spaces_.  This is why the examples you show make no mention of spaces.  They aren't part of the grammar stage, they are part of the _lexing_ stage. `cv-qualifier cv-qualifier-seq_opt` doesn't mention whitespace, because there is no such thing as whitespace during this stage.  it's one token immediately followed by another token.  There doesn't even have to be a space there in the code, if you use a macro. (Macros are a third seperate stage, so that's not "cheating", that's the _point_)

Comment: @MooingDuck Every stage of processing begins with the original string of characters in the source code file, which must obey proper syntax (including proper syntax for macros).  Note that the examples I've shown actually aren't examples; they're definitions within the standard itself, that describe the rules for proper source code prior to ANY phase of translation.  My question isn't about the relevance or presence of spaces after any stage of processing; it's about how to interpret the standard in terms of valid source code.  (Granted, this is a trivial case, but I hope it makes sense.)

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: no, each stage of processing begins with the results of the prior step, otherwise macros wouldn't work.  Those declarations describe what the _tokens_ must be in the _seventh_ phase of translation.  There's no comments at this phase either, otherwise _every single rule_ would have to have a "there can be an optional comment" between _every single token in the specification_.  But they don't have to, because at this stage, like spaces, the comments have already been removed.  If you can find a way to type `cv-qualifier cv-qualifier-seq_opt` without spaces, that's totally valid.

Comment: @MooingDuck I stand corrected - each stage of processing begins with the results of the prior.  What I *meant* to say is that the *first* stage of processing begins with the original string of characters in the source code file.  This original string of characters must obey the proper syntax, and it's how to understand the rules of that syntax, from the standard, that I'm asking about.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: That would require quite a bit of reverse engineering to work your way past the macros and unicode character bits.

Comment: @MooingDuck Rici went through this hassle, and got it exactly right in his answer & the comments that follow.

Answer (score 6):

I'm reasonably certain there is no more direct explanation of this fact in the standard.

The notation used is similar enough to typical BNF that they take many of the same general conventions for granted, including the fact that whitespace in the notation has no significance beyond separating the tokens of the BNF itself -- that if/when whitespace has significance in the source code beyond separating tokens, they'll include notation to specify it directly (e.g., for most preprocessing directives, the `new-line` is specified directly:

# ifdef *identifier new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*

or:

# include *< h-char-sequence> new-line*

The blame for that *probably* goes back to the Algol 68 standard, which went so far overboard in its attempts at precisely specifying syntax that it was essentially impossible for anybody to read without weeks of full-time study<sup>1</sup>. Since then, any more than the most cursory explanation of the syntax description language leads to rejection on the basis that it's too much like Algol 68 and will undoubtedly fail because it's too formal and nobody will ever read or understand it.

---

<sup>1</sup> How could it be that bad you ask? It basically went like this: they started with a formal English description of a syntax description language. That wasn't used to define Algol 68 though -- it was used to specify (even more precisely) *another* syntax description language. That *second* syntax description language was then used to specify the syntax of Algol 68 itself. So, you had to learn two separate syntax description languages *before* you could start to read the Algol 68 syntax itself at all. As you can undoubtedly guess, almost nobody ever did.

Comment: In my question I've added an addendum which includes counterexamples: cases where the whitespace, present in the syntax description, either *does* need to be present in the source code, or is optional in the source code; but where no "whitespace" identifier is added in the syntax notation.  It seems that readers are supposed to understand this from context.  Obviously, I know that whitespace can't be present between digits in an integer, but I was reading the specification under the assumption that the syntax description used would be rigorously uniform and techically exact.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: We don't live in a vacuum filled only with technical documents. Yes, you need to know that numbers aren't suppose to have spaces in them; big deal! There's a point where your goal for technicality has less merit than simply leaving it to the reader to know what to do.

Comment: @GManNickG Maybe.  I know that in the world of physics, this sloppiness is rarely present.  Part of my question is really just that I want to know what to expect in the world of computer science.  I didn't know if I was unable to understand the C++ standard, or if the standard just doesn't discuss this.  In a trivial case such as this, it's an irrelevant question.  However, it might not be trivial or irrelevant in a more complex case, so I wanted to clarify what to expect.

Answer (score 3):

The Standard actually has two separate grammars.

The preprocessor grammar, described in sections 2 and 16, defines how a sequence of source characters is converted to a sequence of preprocessing tokens and whitespace characters, in translation phases 1-6.  In some of these phases and parts of this grammar, whitespace is significant.

Whitespace characters which are not part of preprocessing tokens stop being significant after translation phase 4.  The Standard explicitly says at the start of translation phase 7 to discard whitespace characters between preprocessing tokens.

The language grammar defines how a sequence of tokens (converted from preprocessing tokens) are syntactically and semantically interpreted in translation phase 7.  There is no such thing as whitespace in this grammar.  (By this point, `' '` is a *character-literal* just like `'c'` is.)

In both grammars, the space between grammar components visible in the Standard has nothing to do with source or execution whitespace characters, it's just there to make the Standard legible.  When the preprocessor grammar depends on whitespace, it spells it out with words, for example:

> *c-char*:
>
> any member of the source character set except the single-quote `'`, backslash `\`, or new-line character
>
> *escape-sequence*
>
> *universal-character-name*

and

> *control-line*:
>
> ...
>
> `# define` *identifier lparen identifier-list*[opt] `)` *replacement-list newline*
>
> ...
>
> *lparen*:
>
> a `(` character not immediately preceded by white-space

So there may not be whitespace between digits of an *integer-literal* because the preprocessor grammar does not allow it.

One other important rule here is from C++11 2.5p3:

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character:
>
> - If the next character begins a sequence of characters that could be the prefix and initial double quote of a raw string literal, such as `R"`, the next preprocessing token shall be a raw string literal. ...
> - Otherwise, if the next three characters are `<::` and the subsequent character is neither `:` nor `>`, the `<` is treated as a preprocessor token by itself and not as the first character of the alternative token `<:`.
> - Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail.

So there must be whitespace between `const` and `volatile` tokens because otherwise, the longest-token-possible rule would convert that to a single *identifier* token `constvolatile`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I wish I could understand how the rules you've quoted explain how to interpret the language specification (to make it clear why, from the standard, there can't be a space between digits in the simple (trivial) case of an integer literal, whereas in other analogous examples there must be a separator), but after staring at this for a while I still can't figure it out.